# Find Django model records that have more than one 'child' objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have two models in Django, `Parent` and `Child`, where `Child` has a foreign key relationship to `Parent` like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, default='no name')

class Child(models.Model):
    child_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False, default='no name')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('app.Parent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

How can I find all `Parent` records that have **at least** two `Child` records? Ideally, the solution would use a single `.filter()` statement on `Parent`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate on the number of `Child`s and then filter on that number, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Parent.objects.annotate(
    nchild=Count('child')
).filter(nchild__gt=1)
```

This will generate a query like:

```
SELECT parent.*, COUNT(child.id) AS nchild
FROM parent
LEFT OUTER JOIN child ON parent.id = child.parent_id
GROUP BY parent.id
HAVING COUNT(child.id) > 1
```

One can change the `.filter(..)` condition to all sorts of conditions on the number of childs `nchilds`, for example `nchild=4` filters on `Parent`s with exactly four children, whereas `~Q(nchild=7)` will exclude all `Parent`s with exactly seven children. We can thus make more complicated filters.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!